# Changing link appearance in Default VS2012 ASP.Net Site.Master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I create a new ASP.Net Web Forms Application under Visual C#, there are a few pages that come pre-built.  Part of the Site.Master pre-built page is the links to Login and Register.

```
<div class="loginDisplay">
    <section id="login">
        <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="registerLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Register.aspx">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a id="loginLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Login.aspx">Log in</a></li>
                </ul>
            </AnonymousTemplate>
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                <p>
                    Hello, <a runat="server" class="username" href="~/Account/Manage.aspx" title="Manage your account">
                        <asp:LoginName runat="server" CssClass="username" /></a>!
                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
                </p>
            </LoggedInTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
    </section>
</div>
```

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to change the appearance of those links.  I've incorporated a little of my own css, but now it looks like this:

[image]

How can I change those links so they better blend in with my background?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this?... I am guessing you started with the VS ASP.net web app template.  This uses Bootstrap.  The styles for all of the app are defined in the bootstrap style sheet.  In Solution Explorer, under your project, go to the content folder and look at the bootstrap.css file.

If this is indeed the case, you will also need to get into learning about Bootstrap if you have not already.

Comment: Darn.  This is the first time I'm doing one from scratch and you're exactly right.  I just commented out the line **<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />** that was in the Head section of Site.Master and the formatting of that part completely changed.  Time to tinker with some css now.  Thanks!